# Calculated columns using ID field not showing all details

Tags: calculated-column, list-form

I am a Sharepoint site admin without any development tools, I'm solely battling on with the Sharepoint web front end.   What I would like to do is to create list items and generate a unique reference for each which can be shown when the line is edited or when sent as an RSS feed item.    Presently I have a calculated field which consists of 3 concatanated fields, [dept] + [ID] + [change type].

The problem I have is that ID disappears when the item is edited or displayed as an RSS item ?   I can only think that this is not a stored value but one calculated as the record is displayed ?

Comment: Should mention that I'm using SP 2007.

Answer (score 1):

It is related to this question I think: [Calculation field randomly forgets ID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53557/calculation-field-randomly-forgets-id) or this one [Calculated Hyperlink Column - Lost ID-Field Value Upon Editing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41963/calculated-hyperlink-column-lost-id-field-value-upon-editing)

ID is not supported in calculated columns and always disappear. I mean when you open list settings, check cal. column settings or change something in formula and hit OK, will be visible (for a while), but later when you add new item, new calculated value field will be blank again.